# Saving all visible content over and over with ascending names in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, save

I make animation in photoshop by drawing a layer by layer,so my problem is that I want to ,by pressing a single button run an action, that would save the whole visible thing,the last layer and the background, as a seperate png file, and then continue working with all the layers I had (so that nothing merges) and by every time I would do that the names of these files would ascend ,meow1, meow2.... .Just by looking at it I thought its not that big of a problem, but I just cant find a solution. 
It would save a lot of time since I have thousands of layers to save.
Thanks for any advice or idea.
(i am sorry if my english doesnt sattisfy you:)

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! In order to better help you I think you'll need to clarify a few things. Am I understanding you correctly if I say that what you want to do is to save a snapshot of your Photoshop composition as it is at the time and then continue working as usual? If so, could you not simply create an Action that saves your composition as a png?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to save multiple layers as separate gif, png, jpg etc formats. To do this you must first select File> Generate> Image Assets

[image: Check the image assets so its active]

In your layers panel rename each layer as the format you would like to out put eg:

Layer 1 = (Meow 1.png)
Layer 2 = (Meow 2.png)
Layer 3 = (Meow 3.gif)
Layer 4 = (Meow 4.jpg)

Once you have renamed the layers as above, when saving the psd file it will generate a folder on your desktop and will place each layer file in this folder as per the file naming convention you created.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that wouldn't require you to rename your layers is using the Layer Comps feature:

1) Open the Layer Comps palette by going to Window > Layer Comps

2) Have only the layer you want in the first slide (saved file) as visible, all others off.

3) Click the "New Layer Comp" icon in the bottom right of the menu, exactly as if you were making new layer. You can name this anything you want; subsequent steps will automatically add the numbering you asked about.

4) Repeat this for every layer you have in the file.

5) When you have all the Layer Comps you need to export, go to File > Scripts > Layer Comps to Files, and set the settings as needed (jpg, png, save location, etc).

[image]

[image]

6) This will save your files in the format selected, along with a numerical naming convention. (You may want to adjust this to your liking, as it uses both numbering and the name you gave the Layer Comp)

[image]

Comment: I *think* the main issue with this as a solution is that the background layer is omitted. However these slides can further be run through a batch process that adds the background layer and the save-and-close.